# Battery life way shorter in Ubuntu than Windows

Tags: nvidia, battery, gpu, optimization

I have a Samsung Expert X50 NP350XBE-XH3BR with an Intel Core i7-8565U, iGPU Intel UHD Graphics 620 and a dGPU Nvidia GeForce MX110. My machine comes originally with Windows 10, but I switched to Ubuntu 20.04. In Windows, I can achieve about 6h of battery life, but under Linux it's dramatically reduced to 1h.

I've installed [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) and ran with these configurations:

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT="powersave"
CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT="power"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="medium_power max_performance"
INTEL_GPU_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT="600"
INTEL_GPU_BOOST_FREQ_ON_BAT="700"
# Because I have NVIDIA GPU:
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="mei_me"
```

It seems that TLP is acting, as now my battery lasts 2h long. However, it's still way shorter than Windows.

I've also tried to use [auto-cpufreq](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq), and now I can achieve 3 hours of power doing simple tasks.

I can disable NVIDIA's GPU using `nvidia-settings`, but I don't know if it would mean just throwing my dGPU in the trash and never using it.

Could anyone help me with this optimization?

Comment: From what I understand even if you turn off the dGPU it still draws power. Nvidia knows about power drain and doesn't really care: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unreasonable-high-power-draw-on-linux-compared-to-windows/107891/2